# How does Visual Studio determine which SSH and arguments to use?

Tags: macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

We have a machine running Visual Studio 2022 17.6.3 that we use to build our Xamarin projects. We recently upgraded our macOS to Ventura and since have not been able to pair Visual Studio to the mac. I have followed the troubleshooting steps from Microsoft to no avail.

I have also run through the solutions offered in this other stackoverflow question but have not been able to resolve the issue.

I also have multiple Win10 and Win11 machines running Visual Studio 2022 17.6.3 where the Mac pairs successfully.

I don't know if Win2016 is related or not but there is a difference between the arguments used by Visual Studio on machines where it pairs successfully.

When it doesn't pair the logs show that VS is attempting to use rsa:

Executing SSH command 'ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -m PEM -f "/Users//Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Keys/" -q -N ""'...
When it does pair the logs show that VS is using ecdsa:

Executing SSH command: 'ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -m PEM -f "/Users//Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Keys/" -N "" -q'
Something is making the same version of VS behave differently. I presume that VS is somehow making a decision about which ssh.exe file to use and then making a determination about which parameters to use based on that but I have no insight into that and I have been thwarted in my attempts to prove that.

I've tried:

installing the latest version of OpenSSH;
renaming every instance of ssh.exe until I find which one it's using and then replacing that one with the latest version;
removing all but the latest version of OpenSSH; and
updating the path environment variable to point only to the instance of ssh.exe I want it to use.
Does anyone have an information about how VS determines:

which ssh.exe instance to use; and
how it determines which arguments to use when attempting to run ssh-keygen?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a question you asked last week and that was closed.  If you feel your question is valid, you should try to reopen it instead of posting another duplicate

Comment: Additionally, Windows Server 2016 reached EOL over 18 months ago.

Comment: Thanks @Jason. I rewrote my question last week in the hopes it would be reopened. 6 days on and nothing has changed. I have asked a specific question about Visual Studio that is not a duplicate of any question I can find. I will remove my reference to Win2016 as it’s not pertinent to my question.

Comment: I’d guess that running on Windows Server 2016 is in fact the underlying cause of the problem

Comment: Thanks @Jason.  I'm now a little confused.  I altered my other question so that it wasn't a duplicate and it's still closed without any indication as to whether it has been reviewed or not.  I raised this question in the hopes that I could get some assistance and this one has been closed as a duplicate of my first one.  I would comment on the original question that my first question was deemed a duplicate of but I don't have enough points for that.  Beyond blocking me getting assistance I'm not sure what this gatekeeping is achieving.